# NameError in Engagements#show Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have been trying to show data from a mysql database in a table called "metasploit_host_notes. I wanted to add a tab on to an existing table called "Notes" and display that data. I am not sure what I am missing but I keep getting this error:

> Showing
>   /Users/angelispseftis/RubymineProjects/vapt/app/views/engagements/_metasploit_tabview.erb
>   where line #40 raised:
>
> undefined local variable or method `metasploit_host_notes' for
>
> ## <#:0x007fe859c93788> Extracted source (around line #40):
>
> ```
> 38    <div class="mTop10">
> 39      <div id="metasploit_host_notes">
> 40        <%= render partial: "/engagements/metasploit_notes", locals: {metasploit_host_notes: metasploit_host_notes} %>
> 41      </div>
> 42    </div>
> 43  </div>
> ```

**_metasploit_tabview.erb**

```
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li role="presentation" class="active">
  <a href="#metasploit_host_tabview" aria-   controls="metasploit_host_tabview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Hosts</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation">
  <a href="#metasploit_service_tabview" aria-controls="metasploit_service_tabview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Services</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation">
  <a href="#metasploit_vulns_tabview" aria- controls="metasploit_vulns_tabview" role="tab" data- toggle="tab">Vulnerabilities</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation">
  <a href="#metasploit_notes_tabview" aria-controls="metasploit_notes_tabview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Notes</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active"   id="metasploit_host_tabview">
  <div class="mTop10">
    <div id="metasploit_host">
      <%= render partial: "/engagements/metasploit_host", locals:  {metasploit_report: metasploit_report, engagement: engagement} %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="metasploit_service_tabview">
  <div class="mTop10">
    <div id="metasploit_service">
      <%= render partial: "/engagements/metasploit_service", locals: {metasploit_report: metasploit_report} %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="metasploit_vulns_tabview">
  <div class="mTop10">
    <div id="metasploit_vulns">
      <%= render partial: "/engagements/metasploit_vulns", locals: {metasploit_report: metasploit_report} %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="metasploit_host_notes_tabview">
    <div class="mTop10">
      <div id="metasploit_host_notes">
        <%= render partial: "/engagements/metasploit_notes", locals: {metasploit_host_notes: metasploit_host_notes} %>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**_metasploit_notes.erb**

```
<h3>Host Notes</h3>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="metasploit_host_notes">
  <thead>
  <th>Note ID</th>
  <th>Created At</th>
  <th>Updated At</th>
  <th>Ntype</th>
  <th>Workspace ID</th>
  <th>Service ID</th>
  <th>Critical</th>
  <th>Seen</th>
  <th>Vuln ID</th>
  <th>Data</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% unless @metasploit_report.metasploit_host.blank? %>
      <% @metasploit_report.metasploit_hosts.each do |host| %>
          <% unless host.metasploit_host_notes.blank? %>
              <% host.metasploit_host_notes.each do |host_note| %>
                  <tr>
                    <td><%= host_note.note_id %></td>
                    <td><%= host_note.metasploit_created_at %></td>
                    <td><%= host_note.metasploit_updated_at %></td>
                    <td><%= host_note.ntype %></td>
                    <td><%= host_note.workspace_id %></td>
                    <td><%= host_note.service_id %></td>
                    <td><%= host_note.critical %></td>
                    <td><%= host_note.seen %></td>
                    <td><%= host_note.vuln_id %></td>
                    <td><%= host_note.data %></td>
                  </tr>
              <% end %>
          <% end %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<div>
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs vTabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#metasploit" aria-controls="metasploit" role="tab" class="tab-pane active" data-toggle="tab">Metasploit</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#creds" aria-controls="creds" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Creds</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#vulns" aria-controls="vulns" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Vulns</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#nmap" aria-controls="nmap" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Nmap</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#nessus" aria-controls="nessus" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Nessus</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Tab panes -->
                <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="metasploit">
            <div class="mTop10">
              <%= select_tag('metasploit_report', options_for_select(@metasploit_reports.collect{ |u| ["#{u.created_at} (#{u.user.username})", u.id] }), onchange: "var element = this.value;$('.ajaxLoader').show(); $.get('/engagements/#{@engagement.id}/metasploit/'+this.value+'/metasploit_reports').done(function(h) {$('#metasploit_full_details_link').attr('href', '/engagements/#{@engagement.id}/metasploit/'+element);$('.ajaxLoader').hide();});", class: 'smSelect') unless @metasploit_reports.empty? %>
              <% unless @metasploit_reports.empty? %>
                  <%= link_to "View full metasploit result", engagement_metasploit_path(@engagement.id, @metasploit_reports.first.id), id: "metasploit_full_details_link", target: "_blank" %>
                  <%# if @metasploit_reports.first.is_completed %>
                  <div id="metasploitListHolder">
                    <%= render partial: "metasploit_tabview", locals: {metasploit_report: @metasploit_reports.first, engagement: @engagement} %>
                  </div>
                  <%# end %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="creds">
                        <%= render partial: "creds_info_tab" %>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="vulns">
                        <div class="mTop10">
                            <% unless @nessus_policies.empty? %>
                                <% unless @nessus_policies.first.nessus_reports.first.blank? %>
                                    <%= select_tag('nessus_policy', options_for_select(@nessus_policies.collect{ |u| ["#{u.nessus_reports.first.name} (#{User.find(u.user_id).username})", u.id] }), onchange: "$('.ajaxLoader').show();$.get('/engagements/#{@engagement.id}/nessus/'+this.value+'/vulns_reports').done(function(h) {$('.ajaxLoader').hide();});") unless @nessus_policies.empty? %>
                                <% end %>
                            <% end %>
                            <div id="vulnsChartsHolder">
                                <%= render partial: "vulns", locals: {nessus_policy: @nessus_policies.first, engagement: @engagement} %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="nmap">
            <div class="mTop10">
              <%= select_tag('nmap_report', options_for_select(@nmap_reports.collect{ |u| ["#{u.created_at} (#{u.user.username}))", u.id] }), onchange: "var element = this.value;$('.ajaxLoader').show();$.get('/engagements/#{@engagement.id}/nmap/'+this.value+'/nmap_reports').done(function(h) {$('#nmap_full_details_link').attr('href', '/engagements/#{@engagement.id}/nmap/'+element);$('.ajaxLoader').hide();});", class: 'w400') unless @nmap_reports.empty? %>
              <% unless @nmap_reports.blank? %>
                  <%= link_to "View full nmap result", engagement_nmap_path(@engagement.id, @nmap_reports.first.id), id: "nmap_full_details_link", target: "_blank" %>
              <% end %>
              <div id="nmapListHolder">
                <%= render partial: "list_nmaps", locals: {nmap_report: @nmap_reports.first} %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="nessus">
            <div class="mTop10">
              <% if !@nessus_policies.blank? && !@nessus_policies.first.nessus_reports.blank? %>
                  <%= select_tag('nessus_policy', options_for_select(@nessus_policies.collect{ |u| ["#{u.nessus_reports.first.name} (#{User.find(u.user_id).username})", u.id] }), onchange: "var element = this.value;$('.ajaxLoader').show(); $.get('/engagements/#{@engagement.id}/nessus/'+this.value+'/nessus_reports').done(function(h) {$('#nessus_full_details_link').attr('href', '/engagements/#{@engagement.id}/nessus/'+element);$('.ajaxLoader').hide();});", class: 'w400') unless @nessus_policies.empty? %>
              <% end %>
              <% unless @nessus_policies.blank? %>
                  <%= link_to "View full nessus result", engagement_nessu_path(@engagement.id, @nessus_policies.first.id), id: "nessus_full_details_link", target: "_blank" %>
              <% end %>
              <div id="nessusListHolder">
                <%= render partial: "nessus_tabview", locals: {nessus_policy: @nessus_policies.first, engagement: @engagement} %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: what is the line : 40 in `_metasploit_tabview.erb` ?

Answer (score 0):

The second "metasploit_host_notes" in line 40 is basically a method call or a local variable.

```
{metasploit_host_notes: metasploit_host_notes}
```

I guess you don't have a helper method called `metasploit_host_notes` defined and apparently there is no local variable with that name. What I am guessing is that you wanted to pass an instance variable with that name (`@metasploit_host_notes`). Define that variable in your controller to the right value and change that piece of code to this:

```
{metasploit_host_notes: @metasploit_host_notes}
#                       |----- here
```